# Orders of coordinates in a linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $X$ be a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For how many permutations  $p$ on ${1,...,n}$ does there exists $x$ in $X$ with 
$x_{p(1)} < x_{p(2)} < ... < x_{p(n)}$?

We can test each permutation by solving a linear program, but this is time consuming when $n$ is large. Is there a quicker way to solve this problem, or at least approximate the solution?

Comment: is $R= \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @mdave16 yes. Corrected.

Comment: You probably already thought of this, but it would probably be faster to use branch and bound along with the linear programming approach i.e.  find $x\in X$ satisfying $x_{i_1}<x_{i_2}<...<x_{i_k}$  for all subsets $\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}$ of  $\{1,\dots , n\}$, pruning when you fail to find a solution.

Comment: @mm8511 Yes, but even this approach will take quite a while for large $n$.

Comment: agreed... just a thought, every subspace of $R^n$ with dimension $k$ is (in a sense) isomorphic to the space spanned by some subset of $k$ standard basis vectors. For the standard basis vectors counting the number of permutations is easy. There are $k!$ (just weight them according to the permutation you need). This leads me to think that  it should be proportional to the dimension of the subspace.

Comment: @mm8511 the dimension of the subspace certainly plays a role, but there's more to it. The subspace spanned by $(1,1)$ in $R^2$ has zero such permutations, while the subspace spanned by $(1,2)$ has two such permutations.